# How to tell apart XML single tag from tag pair using DOM in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm using DOM to parse XML, and I want to be able to tell apart the XML files

```
<a><b/></a>
```

and

```
<a><b></b></a>
```

How do I do this? I know how to retrieve the `b` tag as a node, but there doesn't seem to be a method I can use for this task in the `Node` or `Element` class.

Comment: They're structurally equivalent. You can't tell them apart in the DOM.

Comment: You can't. Nor should you try; they are not important differences.

Comment: I am not that much of an in-depth XML expert, but these two snippets seem to be different syntax representations for the exact same XML tree, so a parser won't show you any difference. You would have to compare the raw strings of the XML code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Well, based on your answers it seems I don't need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two forms are defined to be equivalent and therefor indistinguishable to DOM based models.

The relevant part of the spec is the definition and surrounding content at http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-empty

> [Definition: An element with no content is said to be empty.] The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag.

Spec recommends for compatibility but does not require, that contentspec=EMPTY elements e.g. 
 use the empty-element style tags and others use the paired syntax e.g.  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e2480